# How to set multiple stores and display in frontend?

Tags: magento2, multistore

I have created multiple websites, stores and store views in the admin panel as shown in the screenshot. I want to create multiple stores with the folder structure as:

```
www.abc.com/india
www.abc.com/uk
www.abc.com/australia
```

and so on.

How do I display the stores on the front end and get the stores select option so that users can select the stores.

I am using Magento CE 2.1

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This link will shows [how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html)
admin and for fronted you need to create a symlinks for your storeviews [how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts.html)